# JOOQ: Select keys from a table not present in another table

Tags: java, sql, jooq

How to get all the keys in one table that are not present in another table in jooq? Or what is will be equivalent of the following SQL command:

```
SELECT ID FROM A WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM B)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a 1:1 translation to jOOQ:

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(A.ID)
   .from(A)
   .where(A.ID.notIn(select(B.ID).from(B)))
   .fetch();
```

The above is assuming a static import as such:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

#### A note on using `NOT IN`

The SQL `NOT IN` predicate only works correctly when the subquery does not yield any `NULL` values. [In the presence of a single `NULL` value, the entire predicate will not return any rows](https://blog.jooq.org/2012/01/27/sql-incompatibilities-not-in-and-null-values/).

It is often better to use `NOT EXISTS` [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45693158/521799). Or in jOOQ:

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(A.ID)
   .from(A)
   .where(notExists(selectOne().from(B).where(B.ID.eq(A.ID))))
   .fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID FROM A WHERE not exists (SELECT ID FROM B where B.ID = A.ID )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select id from A
   Minus
Select id from B; -- all from A where not in B

Select id from B
  Minus
Select id from A; -- all from B where not in A
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use left join in that case, it is just one query

```
SELECT A.ID FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID WHERE B.ID IS NULL;
```